# Unexpected token '<' in Chrome for react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, react-router

I've been trying to figure this out all day and can't quite understand what's going on. With the following configuration when I'm using npm start it doesn't throw any exceptions in the console, yet when I view it in chrome I get the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Below are my configuration files, any pointers would be greatly appreciated. So far I've tried using npm install babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-react babel-preset-es2015 and those haven't helped either...

main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './jsx/App.jsx';


ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
document.getElementById('app'));
```

package.json

```
{
 "name": "whatever",
 "version": "1.0",
 "description": "none",
 "main": "main.js",
 "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
 },
 "author": "Garrett",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
   "react": "^15.6.1",
   "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
   "react-router": "^3.0.0",
   "webpack": "^2.2.0",
   "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.5"
 },
 "devDependencies":{
   "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
   "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
   "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
   "eslint": "^3.10.2",
   "eslint-config-standard": "^6.2.1",
   "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.3.2",
   "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.7.1",
   "eslint-plugin-standard": "^2.0.1",
   "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
   "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
   "webpack": "2.2.0",
   "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.5"
  }
 }
```

webpack.config.js

```
  var config = {
    entry: './main.js',

    output: {
        path:'./',
        filename: 'index.js',
    },

    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 8080
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',

                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
               }
          },
            {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
            {test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader'}
        ]
    }
 };

 module.exports = config;
```

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory} from 'react-router';

//Page Imports
import Home from './pages/Home.jsx';
import p404 from './pages/p404.jsx';

import Content from './Content.jsx';

var css = require("../css/index.css");

class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
    render(){
        return(
        <div>
            <Router history={hashHistory}>
                <Route path="/" component={Content}>
                    <IndexRoute component={Home}></IndexRoute>
                    <Route path="home" component={Home}></Route>
                    <Route path="404" component={p404}></Route>
                    <Route path="*" component={p404} />
                </Route>
            </Router>
        </div>
        );  
    }
}

export default App;
```

If you need any more information I can provide it, thanks in advance to anyone who can help me out.

Comment: In your code you have <App/>. It should be self closing tag. So after app there should be space. Like <App />.

Comment: Can we see App.js ?

Comment: Just added it, thanks. I will add the space and see if that does anything, although I'm not sure that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using a webpack 1 config, whilst you're using webpack 2, more specifically:

Your "loaders" array should be "rules", "query" should be "options", example:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',

            options: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
           }
      },
        {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
        {test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader'}
    ]
}
```

Also, you need to have babel-loader and babel-core installed (you mentioned you installed them, but they're not in your package.json)

Comment: I installed them just using the npm package manager, such as npm install babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-react babel-preset-es2015... would this cause issues if it's not in the package.json?

Comment: I also added your changes to my config file and that doesn't seem to have changed anything.

Comment: Try updating webpack-dev-server, your current version is also for webpack 1 it seems

Comment: Hmm okay I did that and got the "./ is not an absolute path error", changed it to __dirname, and now back to square 1...